# Which paper is implemented in the Posenet model provided by Google

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

A tensorflow model of Posent by google is [available here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/posenet)

The tensorflow team has also shared this [blog post on posenet](https://medium.com/tensorflow/real-time-human-pose-estimation-in-the-browser-with-tensorflow-js-7dd0bc881cd5) along with the github repo above. Now In the Blog post the author provide links to the two following papers:

- [***Towards Accurate Multi-person Pose Estimation in the Wild***](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.01779)
- [***PersonLab: Person Pose Estimation and Instance Segmentation with a Bottom-Up, Part-Based, Geometric Embedding Model***](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.08225)

In the post its not clearly mentioned which of the paper is the model based on so can you tell me which paper's implementation is being used by the posenet model in Github repo above or the [tflite version of posenet which is available here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/pose_estimation/overview)

By reading the github repo above I'm thinking that *single pose detection* is being done by the first paper and *multi pose detection* uses the second paper, is that correct? And which paper does the tflite version of posenet uses?

Can you please clear up these confusions.

Answer (score 0):

**Your assumptions is correct**

based on the blog post in regards to Multi-person Pose Estimation Algorithm

> fast greedy decoding algorithm from the research paper PersonLab:
> Person Pose Estimation and Instance Segmentation with a Bottom-Up,
> Part-Based, Geometric Embedding Model.

It can be concluded that the first paper i.e *Towards Accurate Multi-person Pose Estimation in the Wild* is used for the Single-person Pose Estimation. Since, the methodology of using Heat maps and offset vectors for single-person mentioned in the blog post is identical to the one explained in the above paper.

**Coming to TFlite**, both the TensorFlow.js and TFlite are derived from the same Posenet model.

Comment: Hi, the answer is still not satisfactory but thanks for trying, I've given the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

The following is all my assumuption:

I think the posenet is currently become bottom-up approach. The reason that I assume this is because in the blog, it has clearly stated that for multi-person detection,

"Moreover, an attractive property of this algorithm is that performance is not affected by the number of persons in the input image. Whether there are 15 persons to detect or 5, the computation time will be the same."

If the posenet is still remain as the same as first paper(Towards Accurate Multi-person Pose Estimation in the Wild), even import the faster greedy from the second paper, it won't change the model still have to crops how many people in the image as the first step, then have to feed that amount of crop images to CNN such to generate respective heatmap+offset, which will lead to the computation time increase per each person in the image.